# localectl list-keymaps: "Couldn't find any console keymaps"?

Tags: linux, keyboard, archlinux

Recently I start to play around with arch linux and run it on VirtualBox using live cd. I wanted to change keymap, but when I tried to run `localectl list-keymaps` I get the following:

```
# localectl list-keymaps
Couldn't find any console keymaps
```

What's wrong? How can I list available keymaps?

Comment: Maybe you are using Debian https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790955 "Debian uses its home-grown solution with systemd and sysvinit. So "localectl list-keymaps" cannot work."

Comment: If you wanna change default keymap with debian you can do something like this:
`sed -i 's_\(XKBLAYOUT=\).*$_\1"SOME KB LAYOUT"_' /etc/default/keyboard`
but I suggest also reading `man keyboard`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you lack package `kbd`. To immediately fix the issue, I would recommend:

```
$ sudo pacman -S kbd --as-deps
```

But this would not explain how you end up missing it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue running "archlinux-2016.03.01-dual" on VirtualBox and your fix didn't work in my case. First I had to "pacman -Syy" to synchronize the package databases since I wasn't able to find "kbd", then I installed it and kept having the same issue the original poster had.

Comment: If you had to `pacman -Sy` it means pacman's DB was not up to date which means your Arch Linux box itself was not up to date either. You should always `pacman -Syu` before investigating an issue. So anyway I would advise you to update it to see what happens. (Out of topic but: `-Syy` is just to *force* a DB upgrade. You usually just need to `-Sy`).